# Do I need to escape a semicolon in a Perl regular expression literal?

Tags: regex, perl, syntax, escaping

Someone is telling me I need to escape a semicolon in a Perl regular expression literal. That is, to match a line containing a semicolon, I should use `/\;/` and not `/;/`.

From what I've read, the semicolon has no special meaning in a regular expression literal, so escaping it seems unnecessary. I've done some experiments and `/;/` seems to work fine. With warnings turned on and the `use strict;` pragma in effect, `perl` doesn't complain.

Is there some reason why `/\;/` is better than `/;/`? Is this version-dependent?

Answer (score 14):

There is absolutely no need to escape a semicolon in a regular expression pattern. There has not been such a need in the almost ten years I have used Perl and I doubt there ever was.

A concise summary of special characters and escape sequences can be found in [`perldoc perlreref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html).

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps someone thinks that the semicolon needs escaping because their editor's syntax highlighting gets confused by the embedded semicolon. In my experience, most editors have a lot of trouble coping with Perl's syntax. Remember, [Only perl can parse Perl](http://everything2.com/title/Only+perl+can+parse+Perl).

Comment: Wow, PPI looks awesome. And it is a great example of well-written documentation, including a good description of why it is so difficult to parse perl.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this is a habit developed from using perl one-liners on the command-line and not quoting, so the ';' split the rest off into another command? Anyway, like everyone else says, no need.

Comment: @Jefromi Hmmmm ... That sounds like a good guess. I was lost as to why anyone would think there was such a need.

Answer (score 1):

there is no need to escape it.

Answer (score 1):

No. `/;/` should always work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, semicolon is not a meta character, so I guess it doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: @sinan Cause I didn't check before answering :)